# How to determine the length of a quarter wave transmission line which would be added to an existing circuit for impedance matching?

Tags: transmission-line, electromagnetic

[image: This is the screenshot ion the circuit designed. Tx1 is the existing impedance and Tx2 is for quarter wave impedance matching. LTSpice requires us to input Time delay instead of length.]

Are the values I have calculated accurate? With this setup, there seems to be a 90 degree phase difference across Tx2. I'm not sure if the 90 degree phase shift is supposed to across just Tx1 or across both TX1 and TX2.
Also, I had to multiply Td by 3 to reduce the phase shift from 270 to 90.
Are my calculations correct?

Comment: Do you get the right sort of result in your simulator?

Comment: I got a phase change of 90 degree across the quarter wave transmission line

Comment: Is the source impedance supposed to be 30 ohms, or is that its characteristic/small signal output impedance, different from the best-match/intended load impedance? Would a couple meters of transmission line really be preferable to a couple discrete components?